# Will my firebase cloud messaging API still work after my realtime database has been deactivated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I received an e-mail from firebase-noreply @google.com to the tune of:

```
[Firebase] Your unused Realtime Database ‘my secret’ will be deactivated in 14 day(s)
    
    We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:

    any logged-in user can read your entire database
    any logged-in user can write to your entire database
```

I have an app on my Raspberry Pi which is available by web, that will send a firebase message to my mobile phone. It will enable a user (any friend of mine that I chose to tell the url to) to track my position. The webpage on my Rpi contains the API key.

Following this e-mail, should I still expect my app to work?

It's a while since I wrote the app but I do find it occasionally useful. The link that firebase sent me to edit my security settings doesn't work. I think I only had an entry in the firebase realtime database to enable me to get an API key. Please forgive me if I am asking a daft question but it has been years since I worked on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The email is specific to the Firebase Realtime Database of your project, and won't affect Firebase Cloud Messaging in any way. If calls to FCM succeed before the database is disabled, they will continue to succeed after the database is disabled.

Of course, if your app needs to interact with the database to do its work, **that** will stop to function when the database is disabled.

Comment: That's the answer that I was hoping for. The only database used is the very small mysql one on my Rpi. I'll vote this up and accept it in 2 weeks time, once my app is shown to be still functional. This leaves a bit of scope for naysayers to contradict you.

Comment: Accepted answer now that I've noticed that you represent firebase.

Comment: I have been using firebase just for Cloud Messages (Sending notifications for Mobile apps). I am relaxed now. Thanks for the answer